# Simple Shiny selectInput not working with Intersect

Tags: shiny

Is there any reason this wouldn't work? I simply want to see which terms are found in the two selected columns. I figured intersect would do the job, but I'm not seeing results. If this looks alright, perhaps I have some other syntax error along the way? Do the inputs need to be in different sidebar panels?

```
selectInput("data1", "Choose you Input:", choices = colnames(data), selected = "PD.Risk.Factor"),

selectInput("data2", "Choose you Input:", choices = colnames(data), selected = "AD.Risk.Factor")),
```

Output:

```
p2 = intersect(x = input$data1, y = input$data2)
print(p2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! Please provide a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) the next time - this will help to get help.

For our problem. What your snippet does is to compare not the columns of your data frame but the the strings as returned by `selectInput`. What you want to do is to use these strings to retrieve the corresponding columns in the data.

```r
library(shiny)
sample_dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 5:14, z = 9:18)

ui <- fluidPage(selectInput("col1", "Column 1:", names(sample_dat), "x"),
                selectInput("col2", "Column 1:", names(sample_dat), "y"),
                verbatimTextOutput("result"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$result <- renderPrint({
      list(on_strings = list(col1      = input$col1, 
                             col2      = input$col2, 
                             intersect = intersect(input$col1, input$col2)),
           on_cols    = list(col1      = input$col1, 
                             col2      = input$col2, 
                             intersect = intersect(sample_dat[[input$col1]], 
                                                   sample_dat[[input$col2]])))
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```